# Split Table data into two table from one data set in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

- I need to split the number of rows into `two` table from one Dataset in
  ***SSRS***.
- **First** table should have first `30` records and **second** table start with
  row number `31`. Number of records may be increased so this should be
  dynamic. Need to do this in SSRS design only not in SP.
- I have tried Expression `Rownumber(Nothing)/30` in table filter but
  ***cannot*** use Rownumber function in table filter.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use any kind of aggregation in a table filter so you would have to look at alternatives.

If you cannot change the stored proc then you could dump the results of the stored proc into a temp table then do additional processing on that. You can do all this in your report's dataset query.

for example

```
CREATE TABLE #t (myFirstSPColumn int, mySecondSPColumn varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #t 
    EXEC myStoredProc

SELECT *, 
       (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CountryID)-1) / 30 as TableNumber 
       FROM #t
```

This will run the stored proc, put the results into a temp table and then add a TableNumber column which you can use directly in your report